# C# Script Source Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client Assembly in Azure SSIS

Tags: azure, sharepoint, ssis, azure-sql-database

I know the Azure instance supports .Net Frameworks, I'm trying to figure out if it supports Microsoft Frameoworks. Basically I have an SSIS package with Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client reference.

I found this link:

http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/introducing-ssis-in-the-cloud

Comment: Please provide more details of what you need to know.

Comment: How do I get the microsoft.sharepoint.client assembly in azure ssis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [SharePoint Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679) on an Azure SQL VM that has already SSIS installed. You can also install the [SharePoint Online client components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038).